# Generalization of the notion of differentiability on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

This is my current situation: I have just finished my real analysis lectures (measure theory and differential calculus in several variables) and I am looking forward to take functional analysis next. I have time now to do a bit of self-study to prepare for this course. I am particularly interested on a **generalization of the notion of differentiability** taught in real analysis courses. So I did some research. I heard of

- Gateaux-differentiability
- Frechet-differentiability

Since I want to do it right from the beginning, here is my question.

> What is a good and usefull generalization of the notion of differentiability on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in functional analysis (or maybe there is some other field)? Does someone have a good book for studying this?

Comment: Deimlings Nonlinear functional analysis comes to my mind.

Comment: @Thomas Very nice suggestion! Thanks.